# Optional POST parameters in Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a phoenix route that I want to POST some form data to, however there are about 4 fields of the form that are optional (the form is constructed by the end user and therefore these fields may not exist in the POST payload)

In the Phoenix controller for the route, how would you handle this?

For example:

My form has

```
Field1,
Field2
Field3 (optional)
Field4 (optional)
Field5 (optional)
```

And POSTing the form must always have `Field1` and `Field2` but can have any combination of the other fields.

so my controller code so far is like this:

```
def create(conn, %{"field1" => field1, "field2" => field2) do
end
```

How do I make the other 3 optional? If I add them all in then they will be required and I don't want to have to make a function for each of the potential submitted forms as it seems overkill.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The parameters received by the controller are just a map, so you're probably looking for something like [`Map.get/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#get/3). With this function, you can do something on these lines:

```
def create(conn, %{"field1" => f1, "field2" => f2} = params) do
  f3 = Map.get(params, "field3", "my default value")
  # similar for the other fields
end
```

You could also create a map that contains all the default values for the optional parameters and then use [`Map.merge/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#merge/2):

```
@optional_params %{"field3" => "default3", "field4" => "default4"}

def create(conn, %{"field1" => f1, "field2" => f2} = params) do
  # `params` has precedence over `@optional_params`, that's why we're using it
  # as the second argument here.
  params = Map.merge(@optional_params, params)
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much, so obvious now you've posted it :)

Comment: It's working. but three years on, any updates on this, new ways to do this?

Comment: @W.M. what do you mean? This is still a very solid and concise way to do this :).

Comment: @whatyouhide, yes that was a concise way to do it :) I know about the `\\` operator in Elixir, thought it can be applied in the function definition line, tried that but it did not work.

Comment: @W.M. the `\\\` operator is for default *arguments*, not any value. Tbh I think this is still one of the best solutions for default parameters. You can go more complex depending on how you want to put the defaults and if they're dynamic vs static and so on, but for the question I think this is still the answer.

Comment: I think the "elixir way" would be to leverage pattern matching in the def create... portion. The optional params will match the proper pattern. This should simplify the control code around setting things up too.